# Cribbage counting a hand

Tags: cribbage, counting

If I have the following in cribbage : 8H, 8D, 9H, 9D, 10C

I come up with 4 double runs  8H, 8D, 9H, 10C and
                              8H. 8D, 9D, 10C and
                              8H, 9H, 9D, 10C and
                              8D, 9H, 9D, 10C

but I know it's not possible to get 32. What am I doing wrong? Is this 16 or 24?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You can't count it as 4 double runs, as that double counts a number of elements.  It is 4 runs of 3

8H, 9H, 10C

8H, 9D, 10C

8D, 9H, 10C

8D, 9D, 10C

and 2 pairs (the 8s and 9s) for a total of 16.

Comment: It is useful to note that "double run for 8 points" is just a shortcut for "2 runs of 3 for 6 points and a pair for 2 points". It doesn't cover cases such as this, where the same cards are shared across different "double runs". The scoring outlined by bwarner breaks it down to the basic Cribbage elements, which is generally useful if you run into unusual hands.

Comment: We call this hand a quadruple run.

Comment: We call it a "double double run"

Answer (score 1):

I've always called this kind of configuration a "quadruple run of 3" for 16.  There are 4 runs of three (2 choices for the 8, 2 choices for the 9, 1 choice for the 10 or `2*2*1=4`) and 2 pairs.  So the hand is worth 16 (`(4*3)+(2*2)=16`).  Obviously, some quadruple runs also have some fifteens built into them that you have to count.

Keep in mind that "double runs" are just shortcut configurations for (2*3+2) 8 points.  This is a completely separate shortcut.

To round everything out, there is also a triple run of 3 (like 8-8-8-9-T) for 15 points.  It is 3 runs of three, and 3 pairs for `(3*3)+(2*2)=15`.  Note that even in this example, people sometime use the shortcut that trips (the 8-8-8) are worth 3 pairs for 6 points.

---

All of these shortcuts just save counting time.  Remember that everything in cribbage still boils down to fifteens, runs, pairs, and flushes (in hand only).

Comment: I think this answer articulates but I would be more aggressive.  There is no scoring concept in cribbage called the 'double (or triple or quadruple) run'.  There is a counting concept called a 'double run', which allows a mental shortcut in scoring.  The only things that are scored in the indicated hand are the runs (each scored individually) and the pairs (each scored individually).  Compare this to the scoring of 'triplets'.  You get no points for three of a kind, but you do get points for three pairs.